# Указатели и односвязные списки в Free Pascal

Tags: linux, указатели, freepascal, односвязный-список, поток-ввода

Всем привет!

В настоящее время я решаю задачу создания односвзяного списка c использованием указателей применительно к потоку стандартного ввода в языке Free Pascal.

Условие задачи:

**Написать программу, которая читает целые числа из потока стандартного ввода до возникновения ситуации "конец файла", после чего *дважды* печатает все введенные числа в том порядке, в котором они были введены.Количество чисел заранее неизвестно, вводить явные ограничения на это количество запрещается.**

Мой код:

```
   program InputStreamNumbers;
   type
       itemptr = ^item;
       item = record
               data: Integer;
               next: itemptr;
       end;
   var
       first, last, tmp: itemptr;
       n: Integer;
   begin


       while not SeekEof do    {        цикл чтения чисел }
       if first = nil then     { делаем список корректно пустым! }
       begin
               new(first);
               last := first           { создали }
       end
       else
       begin
               new(last^.next);
               last := last^.next
       end;
       last^.data := n;
       last^.next :=nil;

       while tmp <> nil do             {до конца}
       begin
               writeln(tmp^.data);
               tmp := tmp^.next        { переход к следующему элементу}
       end
   end.
```

В данной задаче я использую два указателя first и last, а также промежуточный tmp

Ниже приведена моя схема решения задачи:

```
   first                                  last
     |                                      |
     v                                      v
   item.next -> item.next -> item.next -> item.next = nil
       .data        .data        .data        .data
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде - проект компилируется, но при вводе чисел из стандартного потока в терминале линукса компилятор выводит ошибку в рантайме:

```
 Runtime error 216 at $0000000000401124
  $0000000000401124
  $000000000040104C
```

В документации по FreePascal

```
    https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html#x189-196000D
```

написано следующее:

```
    >216 **General Protection fault**
    >The application tried to access invalid memory space. This can be caused by 
    >several problems:
    >1.
    >Dereferencing a nil pointer.
    >2.
    >Trying to access memory which is out of bounds (for example, calling move 
     with 
     an invalid length).
```

Не могу понять, почему компилятор ругается на разыменовывание указателей.

Comment: Не вижу инициализацию переменных перед циклами. Перед первым `first` должен быть равен `nil`, а перед последним `tmp` должен быть равен `first`

Comment: Герман, приветствую!

Последовал вашей рекмендации:

          1. Перед циклом  `while not SeekEof do` инициализировал `first:=nil;`

         2 Перед циклом  `while tmp <> nil do`  инициализировал  `tmp:=first;`

       3 Перед динамической переменной `new(first)` организовал считывание целых сичел  `read(n)`

Теперь появилась новая проблема - программа зависает при считывании чисел из файла, либо она перестала считывать из файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем решении не нужно использовать дополнительный временный указатель tmp, поскольку он излишен и не используется в односвязном списке. Если бы вы добавляли элементы в начало списка, а не в его конец (как в вашем случае), то он действительно имел бы место. Причём когда вы его используете, вы его не инициализируете. Тоже самое и с указателем first. Перед циклом необходимо его инициализировать, иначе в указателе находится неопределённое значение.
Правильное решение задачи:

```
program SINGLY_LINKED_LIST2;
type
    itemptr = ^item;
    item = record
        data: integer;
        next: itemptr
    end;
var
    first: itemptr;
    last: itemptr;
    n: integer;
begin
    first := nil;
    while not SeekEof do
    begin
        read(n);
        if first = nil then
        begin
            new(first);
            last := first
        end
        else
        begin
            new(last^.next);
            last := last^.next;
        end;
        last^.data := n;
        last^.next := nil
    end;
    while first <> nil do
    begin
        writeln(first^.data);
        writeln(first^.data);
        first := first^.next
    end
end.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: AOIPKN, благодарю Вас!